# Get DHCP lease time information from DHCP client Win7

Tags: windows-7, dhcp

Can I get DHCP lease time information from the DHCP client side?  If yes, how do I do it on Win7?

I have searched a lot for the answer on google without success.

Answer (score 1):

[`GetAdaptersInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365917) and [`IP_ADAPTER_INFO.LeaseExpires`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366062):

> LeaseObtained
>
> ```
> Type: time_t
> The time when the current DHCP lease was obtained.
> This member is only valid when the DhcpEnabled member is nonzero.
> ```
>
> LeaseExpires
>
> ```
> Type: time_t
> The time when the current DHCP lease expires.
> This member is only valid when the DhcpEnabled member is nonzero.
> ```

Comment: Is there any existing program (rather than just an API, and I need to write the program myself) doing this, like getting IP address from `ipconfig.exe`?